# When doing an "Engine Coolant" and "Inverter Coolant" change. Do you use the same coolant type for both?

Tags: toyota, coolant, prius

Well I got my 2011 Toyota Prius oil changed and the dealer wants me to pay $500+ to get both the Inverter and Engine coolant changed. However I feel I'm up to the task for a fraction of the price. Anyway I found the plenty of information about how to change the inverter coolant but not the "Engine Coolant". How do I do the "Engine Coolant" part?

I found this video on how do the "Engine Coolant" part and he uses the same coolant that he used for the invert coolant. Is this the correct way to do it? I am going to using an aftermarket brand of antifreeze/engine coolant but it's formulation is identical (as far as I can tell) to the more expensive Toyota brand.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!